# How to get field's default value from other field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I my module I have an entity "Bill" with two float fields "total" and "remaining" I want "remaining" to take its default value from "total". How can I do that?
I have tried these with but when I try to create a new "Bill" it shows an error "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Float'"

`total = fields.Float(string='Total', digits=(10, 2))
remaining = fields.Float(string='Remaining', digits=(10, 2) default=total)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them `Related field`,

```
remaining = fields.Float(related=total, string='Remaining')
```